# How to directly get same Object properties by manipulation of other keys at initialization

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, this, javascript-objects

**Please consider two thing before any comment/answer/vote**

1. Object is within array
2. I know I can achieve it with `constructor` or
       `function` by binding `this` but I have a condition where I have to
       rewrite almost 100 lines of existing code just to achieve above
       functionality. I search almost everything and now asking from Java
       script Enthusiasts about all possible options with same domain
   Look at the below object.

**Question**:I just want `total` value to be equal to `7` which in current example is `NAN`

```
var demoObj = [{
    a: 2,
    b: 5,
    total: this.a * this.b 
}]
```

how I can achieve it? Please answer with any possible solution not matter how ugly code are I will manage.

**Edit** Someone try to mark it as duplicate to a given link in comments which is not true because there given answers not suite my needs. even in accepted answer there, if you change the value of `a` or `b` after initialization then `total` will change which not suite my case !

Comment: it's can be if total change to function

Comment: `this` cannot be used within objects. In your example `this` will be resolved to the nearest reference which is the window/global.

Comment: @ethane not it's not I can't find my answer with discussed link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use an IIFE or it is too ugly / out of the scope of your question?

```js
var demoObj = [
  ((a, b) => ({ a, b, total: a * b }))(5, 2)
]

console.log(demoObj)
//  [
//    {
//      "a": 5,
//      "b": 7,
//      "total": 10
//    }
//  ]
```

Comment: I like it, let me check it how can I integrate it with my context